# C# Input system - Since '{method}' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Tags: c#

Trying a shot to a little advanced text adventure here, I have an inventory class. (isn't an error) and it all works great! 
I'm trying to implement a feature of an input. That it just leads to input, and then returns the arguments back to that class. I thought it would be easy. Turned out a 'void' method can't return something. I don't know what I should use then.
I searched a bit on Google but can't find google, and the answers on here are all XML or more experienced programmers. There are also a few simpler once, but those are unanswered.

This is my Program class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Inventory_system_test
{
    class Program
    {
        //Objects
        static private Inventory inv = new Inventory();

        //strings
        static private string args;
        //variables



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Write("Do you want to kill dave?");
            input();
        }

        static public void input()
        {

            bool done = false;

            Writen("Enter a command: ");
            args = Console.ReadLine();
            while (!done)
            {
                if (args.Contains("add inv "))
                {
                    args = args.Split()[2];
                    inv.additem(args);

                }
                else if (args.Contains("remove inv "))
                {
                    args = args.Split()[2];
                    inv.removeitem(args);

                }
                else if (args.Contains("see inv"))
                {
                    Write("INVENTORY:");
                    inv.getinv();
                }
                else if (args == "close")
                {
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    done = true;
                    return args; ///**Here is the error ofcourse.**
                }

            }
        } //Input files things :)


        #region Easy Commands (Write, Sleep)
        //Write to console
        public static void Write(string writev)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(writev);
        }

        //Sleep for 'int sleeptime' in milliseconds
        public static void Sleep(int sleeptime)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleeptime);
        }

        public static void Writen(string writen)
        {
            Console.Write(writen);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I'm getting to understand scripting more and more, and that's just by asking question and searching Googles, I really love the people on Stackoverflow! Thank you all for your help!

So uh.. how would I go and do this? 
There aren't many methods.. And I wouldn't know what to do from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Turned out a 'void' method can't return something. I don't know what I should use then.

You should use a method which is declared to return the kind of information you want to return! When a method is `void`, that specifically means it's not *meant* to return anything.

In this case it looks like you're trying to return the value of `args`, which is a `string` variable, so you want:

```
public static string input()
```

Additionally:

- You should follow [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229002.aspx)
- There's no reason for your `args` variable to be static - it would better as a local variable within your method
- `args` is an odd name for this variable anyway, in my view. Given that you're asking for a command, why not use `command` as the variable name?

I suggest you read the [MSDN page on methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx) or look in a good book about C# to learn more about return types, parameters and so on.

Comment: Yes, command is what I was looking for. not args, well. I change it into string, like I did before. Now I get this error: 'Inventory_system_test.Program.input()': not all code paths return a value

Comment: Woops, fixed that, but now my program isn't really working anymore. When I add an item, it just crashes.

Comment: Nevermind again, fixed it all. Looking into .NET naming conventions and I'm going to read the MSDN page on methods. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From [`void (C# Reference)‎`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> When used as the return type for a method, void specifies that the
>   method does not return a value.

But your `input` method returns a value so..

[`Console.ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods retursn a `string` so your `args` is looks like a `string`. That's why you should change your *return type* as a `string` like;

```
public static string input()
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You declare `args` as being of type `string`, so that's what you should return:

```
static public string input()
{
    ...
    return args;
}
```